# Decrease fade animation time for Scrollbar in ListView

Tags: android

I have a ListView with the Scrollbar enabled. I want to keep the fading in/out effect for the Scrollbar, but because I have elements in the background that fade in/out accordingly, I would like the Scrollbar to fade out much faster than it currently does. Is there any attribute that controls this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade` to define the delay in milliseconds that a scrollbar waits before fade out.

You can use `android:scrollbarFadeDuration` to define the delay in milliseconds that a scrollbar takes to fade out.